# Last two alphabets of a link are showing twice in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, letters, alphabet

The Last two alphabets of a link placed in footer are showing twice/repeated in Internet explorer from nowhere.... I am using div based design in xhtml.
 How could I get rid of this error?

Comment: You could show us your html mark-up, your css and post a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us your problem. Also, when you say 'alphabets' do you mean 'letters' or 'characters'?

Comment: I can't see your problem.. I can read about it, just about imagine it.. But I cannot _see_ it. Example please :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're talking about **IE6**.. (or that your page is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode))

That sounds like the "IE6 Duplicate Characters Bug".

More info: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html

This is the *only* thing that comes to mind from the very limited amount of information you've provided.